# View Page (DispForm.aspx) not associated properly for SharePoint list views

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I've customized NewForm, EditForm and DispForm to allow users to create new, edit (with certain permission) and display service requests.

The forms work fine except in my views (e.g. Createbyme.aspx which shows all requests owned by me). Instead of pointing to my custom DispForm `/[site]/Lists/[list_name]/DispForm_custom.aspx?ID=[request#]`, it links to `/[site]/?ID=[request#]`.

Is there any suggestion for a fix?

Comment: Did you use SharePoint designer to do the customization?

Comment: Thanks Gurdas for responding.
Yes, I used SharePoint Designer 2007. One thing I'm not sure why the functionality for Createbyme.aspx changed while I was just modifying New/Edit/Disp forms. Note that date stamp for Createbyme.aspx wasn't changed so looks like it wasn't modified (?).

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this question in another post...

[Restore NewForm.aspx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614767/restore-newform-aspx-file/1619804#1619804)

---

To summarize,

Open the page and select the form control.  Oen the propertis for that control and select the radio button "NEW ITEM FORM". After you save the page you can then select the page as a supporting file for the list and the setting will stick.  Do not select the page as a supporting file first as the setting will not stick... ergo the order of your steps is important.