# Restore NewForm.aspx file

Tags: sharepoint

How do i restore a deleted NewForm.aspx file?
I dont want it back through the recycle bin, since i made a mess of it, i just want to recreate the original file.
Sharepoint 2003 was able to do this.

Comment: What version of SharePoint? This is easily achieved using SP Designer.

Answer (score 1):

could you restore it from the recycle bin and then in sharepoint designer try a "restore to site definition" (right mouse click on the file). P.S. Never change the out of the box newform / editform etc. Copy it, then in the list settings in sharepoint designer (right mouse on list) set the newform property to point to the new copied custom form. This way you can alwys go back by just resetting the property in the list settings instead of getting the problems you have now.

Here's an in-depth explanation: [WinSmarts article](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-5-Customize_the_-and-quot;NewFormaspx-and-quot;_page_for_a_SharePoint_List.aspx)

Comment: Problem with this solution is that even after i clicked restore to site definition, i got my old modified file back (go figure?), which is why i resorted to deleting it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As Colin mentioned, always make a copy.  Of course, you can recover from deleting or corrupting your newform but it's a little bit of a pain. SharePoint's odd behaviour causes lots of people to do this... very often we create a new SharePoint form but the list refuses to use it as a replacement newform or editform so we delete the original.

Off of the top of my head, I believe you can copy the newform.aspx from another list or library and then update the GUIDs in the source view. Once you retrieve the file, however, you will have to complete 2 additional steps in order to get it to work.  SharePoint requires a strange synergy between lists and libraries and their supporting pages.  People are aware of the first, which is called Supporting Files, by right mouse keying on list you can choose supporting files for display, edit and new.  What most people don't know is that these files, well actaully their components, must be "aware" of the fact that they are of type display, edit, or new.  If they are not "aware" then any changes you make to "Supporting Files" will not stik.

To create a new page or update an existing one, locate your newly created or broken newform.aspx, if you are creating it from scratch go to Insert >> SharePoint Controlls >> Form Web Part... select the form web part of your choice and add it.  Upon insertion view the properties of the form control andselect the radio button "NEW ITEM FORM".  After you save the page you can then select the page as a supporting file for the list and the setting will stick.

Comment: Alas, no...
I was hoping this would do the trick but it doesnt.
I tried different scenarios based on this trick, but none of them worked.
I am killing the list and recreating it.

Answer (score 1):

The best options is as follows:

1. Simply delete the bad ListFormWebPart form page if it still exists
2. Make a copy of one of your good ListFormWebPart form page
3. Rename the copied ListFormWebPart form page to whatever the name of the bad one was

This works for New, Edit and Display and is the best option because it basically restores you back to the factory default OOB ListFormWebPart instead of creating DataFormWebParts, which have their pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

I have had to deal with corruption issues with Sharepoint so this is somewhat related.

1. Create a new list and using SPD, Copy the WebPartPages Section:

   ```
   <WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{203BDF1B-4980-4FEF-A4B5-C5A4C4A1BFA7}" >
   ...
   </WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart>
   ```
2. Now in your list with the corrupt or missing form. Create a new form with SPD. Yes we know it's not the same. Bear with me.
3. In the WebPart Pages you copied from the donor list you need to replace the ID, webpartid, ListName id and, ListID from the new form you just created onto the save we pulled from the donor list.
4. On the Newform you just created. delete everything between  and replace with the modified donor webpart you just modified.
5. Save and visit your new default form.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I was able to recover.

Here is what I did.  First, I mapped my Share to a Z drive.

Then, in SharePoint Designer, I renamed my list to list-bak.

Then, I created a new list of the original name (in SharePoint Designer).

Then, I updated the ListName GUID in the EditForm for the New List.

Next, in Command Prompt, I moved my dummy list to bak2, and moved by bak list back to the original name.

At this point, I had my EditForm restored, but it still wasn't working (as it was trying to reference the EditForm.aspx from the bak2 list).

Finally, I moved the EditForm.aspx from the bak2 to the original list, and was able to restore.

I hope this helps some other poor sap.

EDIT: to the OPs question, obviously you would do the same steps, but with NewForm instead of EditForm

Comment: Ummm...why didn't you just create a new list form? And what exactly did you do to "mess up" the original that was so catastrophic it couldn't be restored?